# No repository for "ENTITY" found in "XXX" Connection [TypeORM]

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-swagger

I have **Settings Module** with **attendance_record_options** subservice.
I am calling routes in `settingsController` , from there I am calling `settingsService` which contains object of `AttendanceRecordOptionsService` (interacts with `AttendanceRecordOptionsRepository` and saves data in Postgress Database)

**Folder Structure :**

[image: Folder structure]

**SettingsModule**

```
Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [SettingsController],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: getRepositoryToken(AttendanceRecordOptions),
      inject: [TENANT_CONNECTION],
      scope: Scope.REQUEST,
      useFactory: connection => connection.getRepository(AttendanceRecordOptions),
    },
    SettingsService,
    AttendanceRecordOptionsService,
  ],
  exports: [SettingsService],
})
```

This runs fine without error but when I call any route regarding *AttendanceRecordOptions*, It gives me error `No repository for "AttendanceRecordOptions" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "tenant2" connection?`

when I creates an object with hardcoded values like below in Migration file and saves it, all routes start working and I can store data using routs in controller.

```
const attendance_record_options_repository = queryRunner.manager.getRepository(AttendanceRecordOptions)
const aro =  new AttendanceRecordOptions()
aro.name = 'name'
aro.prefix = 'pre'
aro.shortName = 'short'
aro.description = ' description'
aro.type = 'bool'
await attendance_record_options_repository.save(aro)
```

Why am I getting this behavior from NestJS and TypeORM ?

Comment: no answer yet...?

Comment: This error usuualy happens when you have wrong configs in ormconfig.js

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz , `entities: getMetadataArgsStorage().tables.map(tbl => tbl.target),` this is the dbConfig am using in **ormConfig.ts**